# Maintaining contact with potential employer

Tags: pre-screening, contact

About a week ago I received a screening questionnaire email from a company I am looking to work for. After filling out the questionnaire, I've since heard nothing from the company, and I'm not sure if that means I'm no longer in consideration, or if they just haven't gotten back to me.

Would it be rude of me to check in, letting them know I'm still interested, and , if so, how long should I wait before doing so? I'm not trying to come across as pushy, but I would certainly like to have the position.

Comment: Was there any signs that made you think you would be rude?

Comment: It's probably mostly anxiety making me think that, certainly nothing they said.

Comment: Then go for it. And good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most definitely not rude to reach out and **express** your continued interest in working for them and/or the posted position.  Especially after 7 days.   If there are multiple applicants, this could help separate you from the pack. I'm assuming they already have your resume, so this helps them create a positive perception of who you are than just a name in a pile of resumes.

Using whatever contact info you have, reach out.   Keep it light, keep it focused on your interest and detail that you are happy to provide any further info.